# Can I make use of the "high" exponents here?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

I currently try to factor the composite number $$3^{130}+5^{130}+7^{130}$$ and wonder whether the quadratic sieve can be accelerated because of the "high" exponents. I know that for numbers of the form  $\ a^b+c\ $ with large $b$ this is possible, but I am not sure aboth this case here. The usual quadratic sieve can still be applied since the number of decimal digits is "only" $\ 110\ $ , but I would appreciate a trick, if there is one.

I did not find a factor with ECM yet and expect a high smallest prime factor.

Comment: Computer search finds no prime factors less than $10^8$. How do you know it's composite?

Comment: @J.G. There are several primality tests that work well on large numbers. You could for example prove it composite by finding any $a$ such that $a^{n-1}-1 \pmod n$ does not evaluate to zero. [Wolfram Alpha's primality test](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=is+3%5E130%2B5%5E130%2B7%5E130+prime+number%3F) agrees it is composite.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Of course that works in theory, but I asked the OP how they'd verified this particular number is composite.

Comment: In this case, we have $2^{n-1} \neq 1 \pmod{n}$, so it's definitely composite.

Comment: Modular exponentiation is very fast; it takes under a second to compute $2^{n-1} \pmod{n}$ (where $n = 3^{130} + 5^{130} + 7^{130}$) in SageMath. (This was in reply to a now-deleted comment asking how I did the computation.)

Comment: CAS that I use was overflowed by this, but I did it too.

Comment: Factorization is [here](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000001358375340). The next open case is $n=156$ with already $132$ digits. Here , we will need the trick to find the result relatively quickly.

Comment: @Moo I used the usual SIQS (self inititializing quadratic sieve) and needed about two days for the factorization.